# Wordpress wp-list-pages exclude with page title

Tags: wordpress, nav

I'm using wp-list-pages in Wordpress but I need to exclude some pages but I don't want to use the page id - I want to use the page title to determine which page to exclude.

I'm using this code to get the page id from the titles.

```
    <?php

        $exclude_page_1 = get_page_by_title('pageOne')->ID;
        $exclude_page_2 = get_page_by_title('pageTwo')->ID;

        $pages_args = array(
          'title_li' => '',
          'depth' => 1,
          'exclude' => $exclude_page_1, $exclude_page_2
        );

        wp_list_pages($pages_args);

    ?>
```

This works but only excludes the first pages.

How can I exclude multiply pages using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $pages_to_exclude = [];

    $pages_to_exclude[] = get_page_by_title('pageOne')->ID;
    $pages_to_exclude[] = get_page_by_title('pageTwo')->ID;

    $pages_args = array(
      'title_li' => '',
      'depth' => 1,
      'exclude' => implode(',', $pages_to_exclude)
    );

    wp_list_pages($pages_args);

?>
```